# how to implement non-blocking client in grpc go?

Tags: go, blockchain, p2p, grpc

I want to run different remote procedure on different servers without waiting for a reply from server. and as a server completes the procedure I want to have reply at the client. Can it be possible to do with grpc golang?

I want to implement a blockchain network and I want to ask different peers to execute a transaction but I don't want to wait until one peer provides the output of execution and then I move to other peer.

In other word I want to broadcast the execution of procedure and then have all the answers as execution is being done.

I tried the common methods for connecting client and server but it waits for the response from the server. it will increase the time when execution needs to be done on more peers.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a pub-sub broker, not just a p2p system.

Comment: Are you using `go func()` to spawn separate threads for each server connection? Then you would use a WaitGroup to wait for all the threads to finish.

Comment: No, currently I am not using `go func() ` for anything and I don't know much more about it. Can I use it? Doesn't it require more number of ports for doing it?

Comment: I don't really know anything about GRPC so I hope my comments are not misplaced, but using `go func` with a WaitGroup would be the standard pattern in Go for this type of requirement. I don't know why you'd need more ports, but as I say I don't know GPRC.

Comment: I haven't implemented `go func()` but I think it will be sufficient with some work. So thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
go func(){}()
```

to do async jobs, and you can easy control async tasks with sync built-in package
or use channels to control or sync tasks with it.

https://golang.org/pkg/sync/

https://gobyexample.com/channels

Answer (score 1):

Just simply do the Client-streaming in gRPC
Client send the message again and again when he send all the data

```
 // add stream keyword when use in client side streaming
 rpc HeavyLoadData(stream P2PMessages) returns (P2PMessages);
```

And you can also use bi-directional if you want in continuity

```
message P2PMessages{
    string anything = 1;
}

rpc Messages(stream P2PMessages) returns (stream P2PMessages){};
```

And If you want to do something which has to complete and then you want to send data use lock

```
var lock = &sync.RWMutex{}

// it will lock until your logic completes 
fun test(){
lock.RLock()
defer lock.RUnlock()
//do something your logic
}
```

You can also use this if you have multiple clients make a client and want to send data when complete your logic used

First create client map

```
var clients = make(map[string]string)

//then use the threading in go 
 go func(){
 // maintain here all your client when you want to send the data to whom
 }()
```